# Rails Cache - ASCII characters showing up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, ascii

I'm attempting a simple Rails cache fetch and I'm getting a bunch of ascii characters as a result. I want to fetch something from the cache, if it misses, then just return an empty array.

`Rails.cache.fetch('store_links') { [] }`

When I run it in console as an empty array I get:

`[1] development  »  Rails.cache.fetch('store_links') { [] }
=> "\x04\b[\x00"`

If it helps: This was working in Rails 3 but now failing with Rails 4.

Any information would be helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,

I added `config.cache_store = :null_store` in development.rb.

Interestingly enough though, in Rails 3 this line wasn't there and it was working fine, so if somebody can explain that, it'll be helpful!